# Take Two! (an Around-the-Bend)

Tags: word, crosswords

Here's another around-the-bend. I felt like putting a hidden word in, but I couldn't think of anything good... there's still a word, though. Just unscramble the highlighted letters.

### Rules

- Each word goes from **left to right** on its numbered line, and then continues from **right to left** on the next line
- #20 wraps back around to #1

Example: If #1 was "DEPARTS", then #2 must start with "STRA" and #20 must end with "PED". #1 would be entered as DEP in the #1 row and STRA in the #2 row, so if you read #1 left-to-right and then #2 right-to-left it spells "DEPARTS"

[image]

EDIT: It appears I messed up the pluralization of some of the clues. Namely, 11 is singular and 13 is plural. (EDIT 4) and 17 is plural.

EDIT 2: I'm really sorry all! I think I mixed up two very similar words for #6. Just switch the "i" with the "t" when you enter it in.

EDIT 3: I lied! It's two words! My plurals are really bad today, apparently :(

Comment: Should clue 11 be **citizen** of this world (singular)?

Comment: Ahh yes I forgot to check the tenses. Sorry!

Comment: When you say 20 wraps back around to 1, what about that extra line at the bottom? Is the word for 20 nine letters or six letters?

Comment: The extra line is for you to re-enter 1, so that #20 isn't broken up into 2 pieces. See previous Around-the-Bend puzzle answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think I’ve got the crossword, at least, but not the word:

> [image: wraparound 2]

The extra letters unscramble to

> AROUND AGAIN

Comment: Too fast, sniped by 33 seconds :(

Comment: Question’s still to play for — unscrambling to go...:

Comment: I see "dragon" in there but the rest is gibberish to me :( Post-answer edit: aha, that'll do it :P

Comment: You got it! This one went a lot faster than the last one - are Monday afternoons puzzle primetime?

Comment: Not sure about others, but I answered this one just after work and the last one during lunchtime.... haha Friday afternoons seem to be more quiet on here than other times! Nice puzzle, @bobble

Answer (score 3):

Completed crossword (except for a couple of stray letters):

> [image]

Words are:

> DERIVER, REVIVALS, SLAVIC, CIGARET, TERAGRAM, MARTIAL, LATICES, SECRETED, DETERGE, EGRET, TERRAN, NARRATOR, ROTARIES, SEIDELS, SLEDG??, ??GUM, MULLAHS, SHALLOT, TOONS, SNORED.

I peeked at [Michael Moschella's answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/98776/5373) for the clues #18 and #19.

Some notes:

> The tense is wrong for clue 11 (should be singular) and clue 17 (should be plural). I still don't really get clue 13 but it fits with everything. There's a mistake with MARTIAL / MARITAL for clue 6, as it needs to be MARITAL to fit with the next clue. (I suppose "marital arts" could be on display in romantic films?)

Further progress:

> 15 should be SLEDGING but that's 8 letters; it's got to be SLEDG-something anyway. I couldn't find any appropriate 5-letter words ending with GUM.

The coloured letters are

> RAAADGNOIUN

which gives the final answer

> AROUND AGAIN!

Answer (score 1):

Almost done:

> 1 DER
>  2 REVI
>  3 SLAV
>  4 CI
>  5 TERAG
>  6 MAR
>  7 LATI
>  8 SEC
>  9 DETER
>  0 EG
>  1 TER
>  2 NAR
>  3 ROTAR
>  4 SEI
>  5
>  6
>  7 MU
>  8 SHALL
>  9 TO
>  0 SNO

Answer (score 0):

Some Progress:

> 4: Cigaret 5: Teragram (Ci, Terag, mar)

And

> 8: Secreted, 9: Deterge, 10: Egret, 11: Terran, 12: Narrator 13: Rotaries? (The form is wrong but rotary isn't long enough) (SEC, DETER, EG, TER, NAR, ROTAR)

And

> 18: Shallot, 19: Toons, 20: Snooze? Snores? (SHALL, TO, SNO) (Pulling from Rand 'Al Thor the solution appears to be SNORED for 20)

Comment: The g is not a typo, it stands for something.

Comment: I see, I think I got that now then.